# sorting objects with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, sorting, reactjs, if-statement, redux

I'm currently trying to sort an array of objects that is being returned in my reducer. I want to sort the apps based off of their `name` that is being returned, and where there are still currently some names that are `null` I want to list the `null` names at the end. Currently when I try to add an additional condition I am getting an error `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null` which i'm expecting `null` items just need to move them to the end.

```
// Actions
export const FETCH_MYAPPS_PENDING = 'widgets/apps/FETCH_PENDING';
export const FETCH_MYAPPS_FULFILLED = 'widgets/apps/FETCH_FULFILLED';

// Reducer
const appsSort = (a, b) => {
  if (a.name != null && b.name != null) {
   if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
   if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
  }
  return 0;
};

export default function reducer(state = { data: [], pending: false }, action) {
switch (action.type) {
case FETCH_MYAPPS_FULFILLED:
  return {
    data: action.apps.sort(appsSort),
    pending: false,
    retrievedAt: Date.now(),
  };
case FETCH_MYAPPS_PENDING:
  return {
    ...state,
    pending: true,
  };
default:
  return state;
 }
}
```

Comment: `if (a.name !== null && b.name !== null)` You should probably use an extra equals sign for good practice.

Comment: agreed, good call out @SeanKwon

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Are you sure this is the exact code you're using? (Also, your sorting logic is wrong. Consider: if `a.name` is `null` and `b.name` is `'Foo'`, then you don't want to return `0`, which indicates that they're equal; you want to return `1`, which indicates that `a` comes after `b`.)

Comment: @SeanKwon No, that check is totally fine, you could not access methods on `undefined` either

Comment: That error suggests that a.name or b.name does not resolve to an object with the method toLowerCase on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt. It's slightly redundant towards the top, but it makes sense to have null checks before you check the names.

```js
    const appsSort = (a, b) => {
      //null checks
      if (a.name === null && b.name === null) return 0;
      if (a.name === null && b.name !== null) return 1;
      if (b.name === null && a.name !== null) return -1;
      //check for lowercase
      if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
      if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
      return 0;
    };
    
    var obj = [
      {name: 'apples', id: 1},
      {name: null, id: 3},
      {name: 'Banana', id: 2},
      {name: null, id: 4}
    ]
    
    obj.sort(appsSort);
    
    console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the check for `null` as sort value and sort later with `localeCompare` with a chained approach with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

```js
const appsSort = (a, b) =>
        (a.name === null) - (b.name === null) ||
        ('' + a.name).localeCompare(b.name);
    
var obj = [{ name: 'apples', id: 1 }, { name: null, id: 3 }, { name: 'Banana', id: 2 }, { name: null, id: 4 }];
    
obj.sort(appsSort);
    
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that `a.name` or `b.name` does not resolve to an object with the method `toLowerCase` on it.

You could ensure that the values for both are strings before trying to call `toLowerCase` on them. Here's one way of checking if the value is of type 'string'

```
typeof a.name === 'string'
```

Comment: Im not sure about that; if name wasn't a string, he'd get this error instead. `a.name.toLowerCase is not a function`

Comment: But you're already checking if the name property is null so I don't see how checking the type will fix the error. What you're doing is definitely safer, i just don't see how the statement would reproduce that certain null error.

Comment: The value passes for != `null` but the code breaks because the value somewhere **is not a String** as expected...

Comment: i guess what i'm saying is, if you try an object like so `{name: 1}`, it would give a different error instead.

Comment: @SeanKwon: fair enough. You seemed to have helped the OP anyway :)